# Require module inside a WebWorker in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-worker

i am trying to import an npm module inside my React Web Worker using  `const package = require('package-name')`.
But it gives me the following error :

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined`

How can i use a module inside a worker, is there a native way or some way to bypass it?

I am using NodeJS v18.10.0, Webpack v5.73.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is related to
[Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)
please look at it , you might solved your problem